# Moving files with .bat script on windows 10

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, cmd, move

Recently I wanted to make .bat script that would move .avi files from subfolders in specified directory to another directory.

e.g.

> H:\MAINDIRECTORY\dir1\avi1.avi
>    H:\MAINDIRECTORY\dir2\avi2.avi
>
> H:\MAINDIRECTORY\dir3\avi3.avi

....

To one directory called e.g.

> H:\Movies

I've made script which looks something like this

```
@echo off
move H:\Pobrane\*\*.avi H:\Filmy
```

But when I'm tryin to execute it I got something like this:

```
the file name, directory name or volume lable syntax is incorrect
```

Please help me find a way out from this situation.

Comment: move does not support wild cards

Comment: @npocmaka, move supports wildcards for filenames, not for directories. Try a simple `FOR` loop to iterate over directories and then move the files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As move does not support wild cards you can try with `for /r`

```
@echo off
for /r "H:\Pobrane\" %%# in (*.avi) do (
  move /y "%%~f#" "H:\Filmy"
)
```

Comment: `move` does support wild cards.

Comment: It works but please put some explanation like what is: %%# or %%~f#

Comment: And also moving whole parent directory with specific files would be good

Comment: it can overwrite files, causing data loss

Comment: you have any better solution PA?

Comment: `%%#` is a special variable that is related to for command - try `for /?` in the console. `%%~f#` expands the full file path if the value of variable `%%~#` is an existing file.